# Solving recurrence relation with non-constant coefficient.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

I am facing difficulty in solving this recurrence relation having non constant coefficients. Kindly help

$nT(n) = (2n - 2)T(n - 1) + \log_2 (n/(n-1)^2) , \space\space T(1) = 2$.

EDIT:
$(n^2) T(n) = (n - 1)(n - 2)T(n-1) + 3, T(1) = 0$. 
I was having difficulty solving this recurrence, could you please guide me on how to solve this. Help will be much appreciated

Comment: Let $S(n) = nT(n) - \log_2 n$

Comment: Great.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S(n) = n T(n) - \log_2 n$, then

$$\begin{align*}
S(n) &= nT(n) - \log_2 n\\
&= (2n-2)T(n-1)+\log_2\frac{n}{(n-1)^2} - \log_2n\\
&= 2(n-1)T(n-1) -2\log_2(n-1)\\
&= 2S(n-1)\\
&= 2^2S(n-2)\\
&= \vdots\\
&= 2^{n-1}S(1)\\
&= 2^{n-1}\left[1T(1) - \log_2 1\right]\\
&= 2^n\\
T(n) &= \frac{S(n) +\log_2 n}n\\
&= \frac{2^n+\log_2n}{n}
\end{align*}$$

---

For the second recurrence, let $S(n) = n^2(n-1) T(n)$, then

$$\begin{align*}
S(n) &= (n-1)^2(n-2)T(n-1)+3(n-1)\\
&= S(n-1) + 3(n-1)\\
&= S(n-2) + 3(n-2) + 3(n-1)\\
&= \vdots\\
&= S(n-k) + 3 \sum_{i= n-k}^{n-1}i\\
&= S(1)+ 3\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i && (k = n-1)\\
&= 1^2\cdot 0 T(1) + 3\cdot \frac{(n-1)n}2\\
&= \frac{3(n-1)n}{2}
\end{align*}$$

For $n\ge 2$, $$T(n) = \frac{S(n)}{n^2(n-1)} = \frac{3}{2n}$$

And as given, when $n=1$, $$T(n) = T(1) = 0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! @peterwhy

Comment: Could you guide me on how should I go on about solving this one, (n^2) T(n) = (n - 1)(n - 2)T(n-1) + 3, T(1) = 0. I was having difficulty, since I am new to recurrence relations. Help will be much appreciated

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal Is that another question and another recurrence to solve? Please post another question or add to this question above.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal Updated the answer